# What is the correct pattern for "joining" two entity sets in RavenDB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Using RavenDB within an ASP.NET MVC (4) application, what is the correct pattern for loading a set of related entities and passing them to a view?

Taking Stack Overflow as the canonical example, assume the following entities:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string Author{ get; set; }
}

class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
    }
}
```

What we want to do is display the users information next to the comments under the question, The comments are stored as part of the Question document, so we `Include` the `Comment.Author`

Our query might look like this:

```
var question = RavenSession.Include<Question>(x => x.Author)
                           .Include<Comment>(x => x.Author)
                           .Load<Question>(id);
```

Now we have the question object with all it's comments, and the Raven client has cached all the user profiles we'll need, **What is the correct / best / most RavenDB approved way of pairing the User objects with the relevant Comments objects?**

One thought is that I could transform the `User` and `Comment` into a `CommentViewModel` and send that down to the client, but that seems quite manual.

Another option could be to add another property to the `Comment` for Author, that is `[JsonIgnore]`'d and in the getter, lazy load the user from the Raven session. This feels dirty because the Comment model object would need to hold a reference to the raven session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do it like this:

```
var question = RavenSession.Include<Question>(x => x.Author)
                           .Include(x => x.Comments.Select(c=>c.Author))
                           .Load(id);
```

This works for 1.2, note.
Then you can just call Load(question.Author) to get the doc from the session cache.

Comment: Thanks Ayende, would you advocate doing the second load in the view, or would you do them all in the controller, in a loop and pass them out to the view as a list or dictionary or use a CommentViewModel that had a strongly typed author property?